# AWS Lambda: Why Cloudwatch logs are always synchronous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-asyncio, amazon-cloudwatch

My lambda function reads image names from an **SQS** queue, downloads images from an **S3** bucket, processes them (2 different processing), uploads them into an **S3** bucket, and then removes the image from the local.
I've written an asynchronous version of my lambda function to perform the above tasks in an asynchronous manner using **Python **`asyncio`.  The asynchronous version uses a separate S3 bucket and a different SQS queue.

When I run the two functions, the asynchronous lambda function prints logs in a synchronous order like the synchronous function.
My functions are using **python-3.8** runtime and both have the same configuration.

I'm very new to AWS and Python as well. **Can anyone suggest to me why the logs in Cloudwatch are synchronous?**

For your reference, I'm sharing the original and the `asyncio` implementation below:

**ORIGINAL CODE (synchronous)**

```
    def run(self):
        try:
            messages = self._extract_tasks()
            print("Number of messages extracted from SQS: ", len(messages))
            if len(messages) == 0:
                return

            for image_key in messages:
                image_name = self._get_name_from_key(image_key)
                # print("Image name: " + image_name)
                image_name_without_file_suffix = image_name.split(".")[-2]
                image_file_suffix = image_name.split(".")[-1]
                temp_image_path = image_name_without_file_suffix + "-" + str(random.randrange(100000))
                self._download_image(image_key, temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
                self.bw_image_processor.monochrome_and_upload(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
                self.brighten_image_processor.brighten_and_upload(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
                # print("Calling delete from ImageProcessor.run()")
                delete_file(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to process message from SQS queue...")
            print(e)
```

**ASYNC CODE (asynchronous)**

```
    async def process_image(self, image_key):
        image_name = self._get_name_from_key(image_key)
        image_name_without_file_suffix = image_name.split(".")[-2]
        image_file_suffix = image_name.split(".")[-1]
        temp_image_path = image_name_without_file_suffix + "-" + str(random.randrange(100000))
        
        self._download_image(image_key, temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
        
        tasks = [
            self.bw_image_processor.monochrome_and_upload(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix),
            self.brighten_image_processor.brighten_and_upload(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
        ]
        
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        delete_file(temp_image_path + "." + image_file_suffix)
    

    async def process_messages(self):
        try:
            messages = self._extract_tasks()
            print("Number of messages extracted from SQS: ", len(messages))
            if len(messages) == 0:
                return

            # Process messages concurrently
            await asyncio.gather(*[self.process_image(image_key) for image_key in messages])

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to process messages from SQS queue...")
            print(e)

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.process_messages())
```

Consider the following Cloudwatch logs:
[image]

Like the above traces it seems the **monochrome** operation and **bright** operations are taking place sequentially. This is happening for all the images that are being processed.

**Expectation**
The traces should not be sequential if the asynchronous implementation works perfectly.

Comment: What evidence do you have that tells you the logs are synchronous?

Comment: Please explain what you expect to happen, and how that is different from what is currently happening. Please explain what "asynchronous logs" would look like.

Comment: Hi @jarmod and @Mark B, thank you for your response. Sorry, I missed adding traces initially. Please have a look at the updated description where  I have added a trace sample that shows the operations `monochrome` and `bright` are occurring synchronously. I mean following the same order. But there should be some cases when `bright` operations occur before `monochrome`.

Comment: To the best of my understanding (so not an answer), the `asyncio` is a single-thread task queue that supports cooperative multi-tasking rather than actual concurrent execution. When you call `asyncio.gather()`, you are adding tasks to the queue and then suspending the caller's execution until those tasks (and potentially others) complete. This works well with IO operations, but those operations have to support the async model, which the `boto3` library does not.

Comment: In my opinion, you'd be better off letting the SQS integration work as intended, scaling up the number of Lambda instances based on the number of messages in the queue, rather than trying to manage concurrency yourself. But if you feel you must handle your own concurrency, take a look at the `concurrent.futures` package. Be aware, however, that you must explicitly wait for all futures before the handler function returns.